# Create shared library with extension so

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have c++ shared library project in my eclipse. Project builds fine, but I always need to rename binary by adding `.so` extension. Is it possible somehow set Eclipse to create binary with needed extension?

Comment: What's your linker command line?

Comment: LINKER Command g++ -m32; All options -shared

Comment: No, please give the full exact command.

Comment: You pointed me on my mistake. Problem is solved.

Comment: No, not solved, still problem in Relese. There I have command g++ -m32 -shared -o "libMYLIB"  ./Status.o ./iniparser.o ./logging.o -ldl -lpthread

Comment: Too late into the discussion. I too have had the same problem which is due to  creating Eclipse project as an "Executable" type instead of "Shared Library" type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I see the command line, it is easy to answer the question. `-o "libMYLIB"` -o sets the name of the output file name **exactly** to it's argument. If you want it to have .so extension, set it to `-o libMYLIB.so`.